# My Python LinkedList implementation crashes after second addition to List

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, data = None, next = None):
    self.data = data
    self.next = next


class LinkedList(Node):
  def __init__(self, l_size = 0, head = None, tail = None):
    Node.__init__(self)
    self.l_size = 0
    self.head = head
    self.tail = tail

  def add(self, data):
    n = Node(data, None)
    if(self.l_size == 0):
      self.head.next = n
      self.head.data = n.data
    else:
      self.tail.next = n
      self.tail.data = n.data
      n = n.next
      print(n)
    self.tail = n 
    self.l_size += 1
    return True

l = LinkedList()
l.add(7)
l.add(8)
l.add(2)
```

I'm just trying to achieve `(h)-> 7 -> 8 -> 2 <- (l)`
Where (h) and (l) are the head and tail pointers respectively. The way I'm implementing this the LL is basically the head and the tail pointers, the Nodes chain together on their own, that's why I made Node a super class.

Comment: In your example isn't `head` always `None`? So, in `add()`, `head.next` will fail.

Comment: You use the default value of `head` which is None, and it remains None throughout.  So `self.head.next` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

It should crash on the first addition - when you initialize your `LinkedList` you initialize it with `self.head` set to `None` (the default argument). Then when you call the `add()` method, since `self.l_size` is `0` you attempt to set `self.head.next` to the created node - but since it's set to `None` you'll get an `AttributeError`.

When your `LinkedList` is empty, you should set both its `tail` and `head` properties to the first added element, because in a list of length `1` both head and tail are the same element.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get why you've decided to use this messy assignments. You should assign whole object and then move tail to next if needed:

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, data = None, next = None):
    self.data = data
    self.next = next


class LinkedList:
  def __init__(self, l_size = 0, head = None, tail = None):
    Node.__init__(self)
    self.l_size = 0
    self.head = head
    self.tail = tail

  def add(self, data):
    n = Node(data, None)
    if self.l_size == 0:
      self.head = n
      self.tail = n
      print(n)
    else:
      self.tail.next = n
      self.tail = self.tail.next
      print(n)
    self.l_size += 1
    return True

l = LinkedList()
l.add(7)
l.add(8)
l.add(2)
```

**EDIT** deleted subclassing from Node

Comment: You should also drop the subclassing of `LinkedList` from `Node`, since you never use it and it doesn't make any sense anyway.  After all, a linked list is not a node.  I don't understand OP's point when he tries to explain why he did it this way.

Comment: I'm trying to make a library of datastructures. I figured that Node could be used in a lot of different places (Trees) so I thought it would be a good idea to break it up and make LinkedList just a Subclass of Node that just maintains pointers for its beginning and end. Could you elaborate on why this is a bad way to do it? Why is making everything one big object better?

Comment: Becaue the List consists of Nodes, but is not a Node. It's inheritance in OOP. Imagine you have a class Car and a class Engine. A Car has (uses) engine, but is not an Engine. Therefore Car can be subclassed from say, class Vehicle but not Engine.

Comment: @gonczor could you be a little clearer I don't quite understand your example. In this case how am I subclassing Car from engine in essence? Are you saying that Node should be the Parent of LinkedList and not the other way around, Why?

Comment: No. If you have an object, it has certain properties. In your case you have a data structure consisting of data "cells". An abstract data structure should allow adding, deleting, searching these cells. OK? So, you have a data structure called LinkedList and Nodes being these cells. You data structure uses these cells to add them.

The idea behind OOP and subclassing is allowing to reuse similar structures. But LinkedList and a Node are not similar. Node is a cell and LinkedList is a data structure. You could have BinaryTree and LinkedList and they would have some common properties

Comment: or behaviours. Like adding data cells, removing them and searching for them. This Means BinaryTree and LinkedList could be subclassed from same class DataStructure and implementsame methods like add(), search(), remove() etc. while using Nodes as cells they would operate on. They would need different types of Nodes ofc, but they both are not Nodes, they are using Nodes.